# QTP has stopped recording and spying

Tags: automation, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft, uft-api

I've been working for few months with QTP (UFT One 15.0.2), and today it has stopped recording (when I do the actions no lines are written in the script and no objects are added to the objects repository) and recognizing objects with the spy feature.

I am using the WEB add-in, and as I've been working for months with Mozilla Firefox I have checked that the *WebExtension.xpi* is well added to the browser.

I've tried to open mozilla before and after UFT One, I've also restarted my computer, I've checked the size of the screen browser is 100% and that in the **Record and Run Settings** the option " *Record and run on any open browser*" is checked for **Web**.

[image: Record and Run Settings]

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: The firefox I'm using is: 94.0.1 (64-bit)

Comment: [94.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/94.0/releasenotes/) was released on November 2, 2021; [94.0.1](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/94.0.1/releasenotes/) on November 4, 2021.  Are you sure that QTP was working after you updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked that I had the same problem with chrome browser, so not an Extension problem.

Finally I have decided to uninstall and reinstall UFT One, but while uninstalling an error appeared and UFT persisted on the system.

[image: Uninstallation Error]

After two trys I have launched UFT One and it has started working again.

I am not sure how long it will work.

Answer (score 1):

This situation usually occurs because the company's IT department has changed the related policy, causing the UFT Firefox extension to fail to run normally.

You can check if the **HP.UFT.Firefox.NativeMessagingHost** running in Windows task manager after openning Firefox while the extension is enabled, and check if the **Micro Focus UFT Agent content script** loaded in Firefox debugger's Sources tab(note: you need to check the "Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes" in Web Developer Tools' Setting firstly).

If one of these things does not exist, you should check the policy change with your IT: did they block the related thing running?
If they all exist, you can open a CPE case to UFT One support. They will help you to do the further investigation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have checked with our UFT One experts and no policy has changed. I have posted as an answer my actual solution but in case it fails again I will ask the IT department to open a CPE cause to UFT One support.